# Get index of number if it was inserted into a sorted array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

```js
function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {
  arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  });
  
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { // cycles through the array
    if (arr[i] >= num) { // if array value is bigger than num 
      return i; // return index pos of num bigger than value
    }
    else if (arr[i] === undefined) { // if not found 
      arr.push(num); // push to array 
      return arr.indexOf(num); // return index pos of new num <-- should return 3 in this case
    }
  }
}

console.log(getIndexToIns([2, 5, 10], 15)); // Should return 3
```

The mission of this is to sort an array, and return the index value of `arg2` if it were in the array.

Example: `getIndexToIns([10, 20, 30, 40, 50], 35)` should return `3`.

What I’m having trouble with, is if `arg2` is not found in the array, to push it into it and return its index value. I can’t seem to make it work.

Comment: _"getIndexToIns([2, 5, 10], 15) should return 3."_ What would `3` be returned?

Comment: return 3 is the index position the 2nd argument which is num.
so I need to push 15 into the array, and return index 3 because thats where 15 would be sitting in [2, 5, 10, 15]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to do it:

```
function getIndex(arr, num) {
  return arr.concat(num).sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  }).indexOf(num);
}
```

Sure there a few ways to do this but the fix in your code is below:

[Working Example](https://jsbin.com/zaliqe/1/edit?js,console)

```
function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {
  arr.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a-b;
  });
  for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) { // cycles through the array
    if (arr[i] >= num) { // if array value is bigger than num 
        return i; // return index pos of num bigger than value
    }
    if (i === arr.length - 1) { // if not found 
        arr.push(num); // push to array 
        return arr.indexOf(num); // return index pos of new num <-- should return 3 in this case
    }
  }
}
```

in your code you checked to see `if (arr[i] === undefined)` that will never happen, so instead check to see if you are at the end of the array, and if so, that means you haven't found your number, and then you can push it and get the index.

Comment: I went with this selection because I spent grueling hours trying to figure out this problem and it call came down to my 2nd if statement. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the `.push` and `.indexOf` methods on the array?

```
function arrSort(a, b) {
    return a - b;
}

function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {
    // you sort the array
    arr.sort(arrSort);

    // if it doesn't contain the num
    if(arr.indexOf(num) == -1) {
        // add the num to the array
        arr.push(num);

        // sort the array again
        arr.sort(arrSort);

        // return the index of the num
        return arr.indexOf(num);
    }

    // if the num is in the array, return its position
    return arr.indexOf(num);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just push `num` into the array then sort it out with `map` or `sort`.

```js
function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {
  arr.push(num);
  arr.map(function(a,b) {
    a-b;
     arr.indexOf(num);
  });
  console.log(arr+'\n');
  console.log(num +' is at '+arr.indexOf(num)+'\n');
}

getIndexToIns([2, 5, 10], 15);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your arrays seem already sorted, you should just use a dichotomic search to find the index, and then insert it with `splice`.

```
function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {
  var index = (function search(from, to) {
    if(from == to) return to;
    var m = Math.floor((from+to)/2);
    if(arr[m] > num) return search(from, m);
    if(arr[m] < num) return search(m+1, to);
    return m;
  })(0, arr.length);
  arr.splice(index, 0, num);
  return index;
}
```

Or, since it will be linear anyways, loop backwards manually:

```
function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {
  for(var i=arr.length; i>0 && arr[i-1]>num; --i) arr[i] = arr[i-1];
  arr[i] = num;
  return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {
    function compare(a,b){
        return  a-b;
    }
    arr.push(num);
    arr.sort(compare);
    console.log(num);
    num = arr.indexOf(num);
    return num;
}
```

getIndexToIns([40, 60], 50);

Answer (score 0):

I used **for** with nested two **if** conditions witch counting indexes in variables **j** and **k**.

```js
function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {
  // Find my place in this sorted array.
  var j = 0;
  var k = 0;
  
  arr.sort(function(a, b){return a - b;});
  for (var i= 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if ( arr[i] < num ) {
      k++;      
      if (arr[i] > num) {
        j++;
      }
    }
  }
  return j+k;
}
console.log(getIndexToIns([3, 10, 5], 3));
console.log(getIndexToIns([10, 20, 30, 40, 50], 35));
console.log(getIndexToIns([10, 20, 30, 40, 50], 30));
console.log(getIndexToIns([40, 60], 50));
console.log(getIndexToIns([5, 3, 20, 3], 5));
console.log(getIndexToIns([2, 20, 10], 19));
console.log(getIndexToIns([2, 5, 10], 15));
```

Comment: you do not need that variable "j" inside the if condition.