# JavaScript - Get array element position/index

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, indexof

I have array like this for example:

```
const arr = [3,5,7,10];
```

And I have a number, for example:

```
const status = 4;
```

I have to find index of this number, so number 4 is bigger than 3, and less then 5, so it belongs to second index, I have to get something like position.

Position for the number for should be 2. (it's bigger than 3, but less then 5).

**Expected result**

```
const position = 2;
```

Comment: Please go read [ask], and show us what you tried. This is not a code-writing service.

Comment: Just have a look at this example of a binary search. With a few small adjutations you should get the right result: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search-in-javascript/

Comment: Basically, check your array with indexOf function. And result is not -1 you found it. If result is -1, then add your status to array. And sort your array ascending. And use indexOf again. And your array sould be var not const for this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript Insert into Array and return Index Position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37244841/javascript-insert-into-array-and-return-index-position)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

are you looking for this simple solution?

```js
const arr = [3,5,7,10];

const status = 4;

const position = arr.findIndex( e => e > status) + 1;

console.log(position)
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks so much. Now I see it's quite straight forward.
I made adjustment like this:
const position = (arr, status) => arr.findIndex( e => e >= status) + 1;

This solves the case when the status is 10, position is 4

I'm just not sure how to expand it you pass status 11, then to make it position 5 (bigger)